# How to connect influxDB to hadoop to store influxdb data into hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, influxdb

Time series data are stored in the influxdb, but how to further connect influxdb with hadoop hdfs to store all influxdb data into HDFS.

How the data in influxDB can be transferred to hadoop for storage ?

Comment: Add your code in order to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfluxDB doesn't have any customized tools for HDFS, but there are a few ways to export your data into a text file so that you can then insert the data into HDFS.

The `influx_inspect export` [CLI tool](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/tools/influx_inspect/) will create a text file in line protocol format. You can adjust formats by using the [-format](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/tools/shell/#global-options) flag in the CLI if you need another type (CSV, JSON, and column are available). Getting that data into HDFS would then (hopefully) be much easier for you.

Comment: How to get `influx_inspect export` ? Is there any installation required ?

Comment: No. You can use it from the command line as long as you have influxdb installed.